# How to convert mongodb $date.$numberLong result to a moment.js using JavaScript?

Tags: mongodb, momentjs, isodate

I'm getting the `$date.$numberLong` from a `mongodb collection` to handle in `javascript`.
The `JSON` is like this:

```
[{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5b6ad63479ff904a550957eb"},
    "date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1533686400000"}}
}]
```

If I print the `value.$date.$numberLong` it returns `1533686400000` as well.
But, I've been trying by this way:

```
var date = moment(value.$date.$numberLong);
```

and it has returning `invalid date`.
How can I get it work?

Comment: Try this `moment(parseInt(value.$date.$numberLong))`

Comment: Great! That's working fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/anthony-winzlet) contribution:

```
moment(parseInt(value.$date.$numberLong));
```

it has working now!